# Get penultimate element

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

Is there a way in jQuery using selectors to identify the penultimate element?

Is there something like a :last-1?

The list can be any length so i cant use 'eq'

Any help would be much appreciated.

A.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Can't see your html but try this:

```
$("a:last").prev();
```

That should give you the one *before* the last element.

You could even try this:

```
$("a:last").eq(-1);
```

Comment: +1, Nice solution **but** I would add `.prev("a")` to prevent deleting other elements.

Answer (score 2):

Can't you just get the last element and then use `.prev()` to get the penultimate element?

If you can post your HTML it would help.