# jQuery apply css to penultimate element?

Tags: jquery

I need to apply CSS to the 2nd to last element. Ive found an answer on this in the thread below: 
[Get penultimate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334906/get-penultimate-element)

But how to I change the syntax to apply CSS? The following doesn't work:

```
$("a:last").prev().css('width','250px');
```

Thanks

Ive tried applying @tweak method's but it doesn't work.

```
setInterval(function(){
$(".image-cont:last .image-cont2").prev().css({ width,'250px' })
},1000);
```

Comment: [That does work](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/R5HXK/).

Comment: @Clement What does the OP want?

Comment: Show us your HTML code and pinpoint the element you want selected.

Comment: @BoltClock I cant ftp my files from where I am at the moment (but i could do tonight), is my updated answer sufficient? Thanks

Comment: @jdln: Just try to recall what your markup looks like, you don't have to post up the entire thing. Just the fragment in question.

Comment: @jdln: Just a heads up in case you missed it. `.prev().css('width','250px');` works fine. You just need to select the right element and call :last on it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your post revision, I would suggest:

```
setInterval(function(){
$(".image-cont:last").prev().find(".image-cont2").css('width', '250px');
},1000);
```

But without you posting your HTML and pinpointing the element you need, I'm still not sure if this is the answer you want.

By way of explanation: `prev` goes 'back' from the element you selected, and your selector selects a descendant of the 'last' element with class `image-cont` - so it will select the previous sibling of that descendant. My suggestion will select the descendant from the penultimate element with class `image-cont`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$("a:last").prev().css({ width: '250px' });
```

Comment: This only apply the css to the element just before the last one. OP wants to apply CSS from the 2nd to the last element.

Comment: @Clement: That's exactly what it is.

Comment: Penultimate and second-to-last are the same thing. He's not asking about the element selector, he's asking about the CSS application.

Comment: Oups, I read *"from the 2nd to the last element"*, not *"to the 2nd to last element"*, my bad.

Comment: Ive updated my answer with my use of your code but it doenst work. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("a:last").prev().add('a:last').css('width','250px');
```

It selects the 2nd last and the last element and adds the css.

Comment: I only want to select the 2nd to last element, not the last one aswell. Thanks

Comment: Ups, read the question wrong, sorry.
try this, this selects all elements except the first one:
$('a').not(":first").css('width','250px');

Answer (score 0):

Grab all but the last, then grab the last of that result:

```
$("p:not(:last)").filter(":last").addClass("hilight");
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/ujuku4/edit

Of course, the following will work too:

```
$("p:last").prev().addClass("hilight");
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/ujuku4/2/edit

If you have any problems with either of these methods it would most likely reflect a problem with your HTML and jQuery's inability to properly handle it.

Answer (score 0):

This example will only work if the a tag are in a sibling structure like this

```
<a href="#">a</a>
<a href="#">a</a>
<a href="#">a</a>
<a href="#">a</a>

$("a:last").prev().css('width','250px');
```

If the a tags are inside other tag like this

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">a</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">b</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">c</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">d</a></li>
</ul>

$("a").not(":last").filter(":last").css('width','250px');
```

And then the problem can be that you can't set a CSS width on a inline element, so change the display to "inline-block" or "block"

```
$("a").not(":last").filter(":last").css({
    'width' : '250px',
    'display' : 'inline-block'
});
```

or

```
$("a:last").prev().css({
    'width' : '250px',
    'display' : 'inline-block'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I had the same problem but, with some differences. I wanted to change the focus of my inputs.

So i tried something, my advice is:

`$("#yourelement").eq(-2).css('.myclass');`

or

`$("#urelement").eq(-2).attr({ width: 250});`

It's not necessary to add `'px'` ;)

Hope it works for you!